# How do I install FFserver on macOS?

Tags: homebrew, encoding

I'd like to try FFserver. I've installed FFmpeg (4.0.2) with Homebrew. I've got ffmpeg, ffplay and ffprobe in my path, but no ffserver. In fact no files on my entire hard drive relate to ffserver.

Typing `brew options ffmpeg` does not mention anything about ffserver, neither does `brew search ffserver`. Searching the web for "ffserver missing" does not suggest anything.

So how do I install FFserver? (Or has it been deprecated or replaced or something?)

**Update**: On http://ffbinaries.com/downloads there seem to be no FFserver binaries for FFmpeg 4, so that may hint that FFserver is simply not available for FFmpeg 4. Any information regarding why, when it will be available, and any way to install FFserver with Homebrew is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Well! According to https://superuser.com/a/1297419, "ffserver was removed from FFmpeg on 2018-01-06 due to a lack of user and developer interest." So much for that...